# USING RECURSION IN SQL TO FIND THE LOCATION OF AN EVENT

Tags: sql, recursion

I am trying to determine the location of an event from 2 tables using sql.  I believe that recursion is necessary for this solution, and I'm a bit foggy on that.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

The first table is the movement table. It shows when and where a person moved.  I also included a movement rank, although, I'm not sure it's necessary for a solution.  A person may move back and forth between buildings.

[image: Movement_table]

The second table is the event table.  It shows a person and a time of that person's event.

[image: Event_table]

What I want to be able to do is find, for each event in the event_table, the location of the person.  The solution would look something like this:

[image: solution_looks_like]

Thank you so much for your time and consideration.

Comment: This is not "recursion" in the computer science sense.  It could be done with a nested query, looking for the most recent entry less than the desired time.  I'll come up with an example.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This does it.  This leaves NULL in the column if there is no movement before that time.

```
SELECT et.*, (
    SELECT to_location 
    FROM movement_table
    WHERE person_id=et.person_id
      AND movement_time < et.event_time
    ORDER BY movement_time desc
    LIMIT 1) AS event_location
FROM event_table et;
```

Output (from sqlite):

```
10|2021-07-20 11:30:00|
20|2021-06-29 10:29:00|
20|2021-07-02 04:30:00|BUILDING A
20|2021-07-04 15:46:00|BUILDING B
40|2021-07-07 23:59:00|BUILDING C
50|2021-07-13 23:05:00|BUILDING D
50|2021-07-17 09:37:00|BUILDING D
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did try this.  I had to modify it a little because "LIMIT" was not recognized by my version of SQL.  I ended up using "TOP (1)" at the beginning of the subquery, and that seemed to have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, location for an event is the TO_LOCATION column of the latest movement before the event in the Movement_table. So you need to join tables and select by max(MOVEMENT_TIME) < (or <=) EVENT_TIME. I cannot give an exact sql but it will be something like:

Select e.event_time, m.to_location
From event_table e, movement_table m
Where m.movement_time =
(Select max(m1.movement_time)
From movement_table m1
Where m1.movement_time < e.event_time)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a person is in a place for a period of time.  You really just need the time period -- to get the end time use `lead()`.  The rest is a `join`:

```
select e.*, m.*
from events e left join
     (select m.*,
             lead(movement_time) over (partition by person_id order by movement_time) as next_movement_time
      from movements m
     ) m
     on e.person_id = m.person_id and
        e.event_time >= m.movement_time and
        (e.event_time < m.next_movement_time or m.next_movement_time is null);
```